# CopyFromScreen - check if handle is vaild

Tags: c#, winapi, gdi, system.drawing

I'm capturing screen using [CopyFromScreen](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.copyfromscreen?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Drawing_Graphics_CopyFromScreen_System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Drawing_Size_). When someone locks PC, then it's starting to throw exception `System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The handle is invalid`. To avoid it, I'm checking current session state using [SystemState.SessionSwitch](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.systemevents.sessionswitch?view=netframework-4.7.2). It's a good solution, but when I'm capturing screen with speed 30 screenshots per second, then it is fast enough to fire this exception 1/2 times before I switch flag state in `SessionSwitch` event. Is there any way to check current session state in `catch` block or to check if handle is valid before I invoke `CopyFromScreen`?

Comment: Not being able to reliably tell that the user activated the secure desktop is a feature.  SessionSwitch squeaked past the security review, somehow, it did get added much later.  You might get a better indication from Control.CreateGraphics() producing IntPtr.Zero for the GetHdc() return value.  Not sure, try/catch is otherwise as good as it is going to get.

Comment: Thanks! I'm checking now value from GetHdc() and it seems to be working great! As this answer is in comment I don't know how to mark it as accepted answer. Is it possible in any way :)?

Comment: Lucky guess.  Be sure to share what you discovered in your own post and mark it as the answer.